# How to turn off Chrome's touch events with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, touch

I have a [snippet of code](http://jsfiddle.net/rgelb/76sLggyL/19/) that refuses to work in Chrome on Windows tablets (most importantly Surface Pro), unless I turn off Touch events via the chrome://flags mechanism:

[image]

Since I can't ask my users to change this setting, is there a way to manipulate this setting (or something that does the trick) for my page only?

P.S. The code in question is a drag & drop for Kendo UI Grid and even won't even fire with the touch setting set to Automatic.

```
grid.table.find("tbody tr").kendoDropTarget({
     dragenter: function (e) {...}
```

P.P.S.  I spoke to Kendo folks about and they are saying that this is a browser limitation issue.  They hope to have the issue sorted out when all browsers implement Pointer events later this year.

Comment: I'm having similar issues with `ionic-framework` and windows touch in chrome ..